# Create a task scheduler task

Tags: vbscript, task

For the past couple of days, I have been trying to code a simple script in VB for Windows 7/10, to create a scheduled task in Task Scheduler.

The only working code I can find is this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446862(v=vs.85).aspx

My only issue is I need the task to run at "Startup" that code works on a timer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript for creating a scheduled task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549393/vbscript-for-creating-a-scheduled-task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
const TriggerTypeDaily = 2
```

Add (read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
const TriggerTypeBoot = 8
```

Change

```
Set trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeDaily)
```

into

```
Set trigger = triggers.Create(TriggerTypeBoot)
```

and adapt/remove the rest of the code depending on your needs.